# Does my Sparkle appcast need a sparkle:dsaSignature field in order to be valid?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, code-signing, sparkle

I have been troubleshooting an 'Update Error!' for a few days now with Sparkle and have made little progress. I modeled my appcast after a working sample as closely as I could but I couldn't get it to work. Finally, I just decided to use the sample appcast in my app to test:

```
http://sparkle-project.org/files/sparkletestcast.xml
```

When I put that as my SUFeedURL, voila, it works. So I copied and pasted the contents of that XML to the file on my server and it doesn't work. Looking over the diff closer, the only material difference is the sparkle:dsaSignature, which I don't have a valid value for.

Reading over the [documentation](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/wiki), however, I got the impression that I only needed to deal with the dsaSignature stuff if I am not signing the app myself with my certificate. When I am deploying the build of this app, I am exporting it from Xcode and signing it with my dev identity, and then zipping it up and putting it on the server.

Do I need the sparkle:dsaSignature field in my appcast if I am signing the app myself? I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOW. Just...wow. My SUFeedURL started with `www`, not `http://www`. That was causing the crash and took several hours of head scratching to track down. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.