# Sparkle appcast not working

Tags: sparkle

I'm having a problem getting Sparkle to read my appcast which is in my website's root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<channel>
<title>myApp</title>
<link>http://www.myWebSite.net/appcast.xml</link>
<description>
Generate docs.    
</description>
<language>en</language>
<item>
<title>Version 6.2 (1 new feature)</title>
<sparkle:releaseNotesLink>http://myWebSite.net/myApp.shtml</sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
<pubDate>Sun, 28 Jun 2015 19:20:11 +0000</pubDate>
<enclosure url="http://yWebSite.net/downloads/myApp.zip" sparkle:version=“6.2” length=“1500000” type="application/octet-stream" />
<sparkle:minimumSystemVersion>10.10</sparkle:minimumSystemVersion>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

In my app I've added a user preference:

```
[prefs setObject:@"http://www.myWebSite.net/appcast.xml" forKey:@"SUFeedURL"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

When I select my 'Check for updates' menu item Sparkle reports it doesn't seem to like the feed and logs:

```
Sparkle: Error: An error occurred in retrieving update information. Please try again later. An error occurred while parsing the update feed.
```

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958896/does-my-sparkle-appcast-need-a-sparkledsasignature-field-in-order-to-be-valid) but it's solution doesn't seem to have helped (although Sparkle did work ok when I used the sample appcast). Presumably my appcast is wrong. I'd appreciate some help in correcting it.

Comment: Seeing the same issue, did you ever get this working reliably?

Comment: Nope. I gave it up and wrote my own update server. Sorry not much of an answer!

Comment: I found out that I wasn't properly escaping text in the description key in the xml file. I don't know what the solution is yet, but taking out all text from there (esp words with apostrophes) fixed my issue. Sigh.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the sparkle feed is being served on HTTPS or mark 'Allow Arbitrary Loads' to YES in your Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

you may also try this hassle-free build server
http://amtourky.me/2016/01/20/mac-os-x-continuous-delivery-sparkler-the-missing-build-server-for-sparkle/